# Component `mounted` fires twice on page load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have a very weird error where on page load a components `mounted` and `beforeMount` fire/run twice? Each of my components represents a page, so when I load the page on `mywebsite.com/contact` the `Contact.vue` functions `mounted` and `beforeMount` fire/run twice but if I load the page on `mywebsite.com/foo` the `Contact.vue` functions `mounted` and `beforeMount` fire/run once (which is what I *think?* should happen).

Any idea why these functions would execute twice? I have a bit of finicky setup but it work nicely for dynamic templates.

`router/index.js`:

```
const router = new Router({
routes: [
  {
      path: (window.SETTINGS.ROOT || '') + '/:slug',
      name: 'Page',
      component: Page,
      props: true
  },
]
})
```

**Page.vue:**

```
<template>
  <component v-if="wp" :is="templateComponent" v-bind:wp="wp"></component>
  <p v-else>Loading...</p>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">

import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import * as Templates from './templates'

// Map templates
let templateCmps = {}
_.each(Templates, cmp => {
  templateCmps[cmp.name] = cmp
})

export default {

props: ["slug"],

components: {
  ...templateCmps

  // Example:
  // 'default': Templates.Default,
  // 'contact': Templates.Contact,
  // 'home': Templates.Home,
},

computed: {
  ...mapGetters(['pageBySlug']),

  wp() {
    return this.pageBySlug(this.slug);
  },

  templateComponent() {
    let template = 'default' // assign default template

    if (!_.isNull(this.wp.template) && this.wp.template.length)
      template = this.wp.template.replace('.php','').toLowerCase()

    return template
  }
},

created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('getPageBySlug', { slug: this.slug })
}
}
</script>
```

**Contact.vue:**

```
<template>
    <main></main>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">


export default {

    name: 'contact',

    mounted() {
      console.log('Contact::mounted') // this outputs twice
    },

    beforeMount() {
      console.log('Contact::beforeMount') // this outputs twice
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: try to add a watcher to `templateComponent` and see if the value has any unnecessary changes ?

Comment: or simple add `console.log(template)` before `return template`

Comment: Could you make a JS fiddle so we can see whats going on?

Comment: Try to print out console.log(this.$vnode.tag) instead. This will display the component name and id; then you can check if you have two different components being rendered.
I had this problem once, my project's css framework (semantic-ui) was rendering some divs twice and setting display: 'none' to one of them. Tricky bastard.

Answer (score 2):

I had (have) a similar issue. I'm not 100% sure about this, but I think the issue may be caused by `vuex`. `Vuex` has it's own internal instance of `Vue` (created [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L273) in the [`resetStoreVM()` function](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L250) called in the [`constructor()`](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/blob/dev/src/store.js#L61)). My suspicion is that this internal instance of `Vue` causes some components to be re-created, which in turn triggers the lifecycle events for those components to fire more than once.

If not in `vuex`, is it possible that you're creating more than one instance of `Vue` (i.e. `new Vue({})`) in your app? Alternatively, is there some code that is causing your primary `Vue` instance or the `Contact` component to be initialized more than once? That's all I can think of that might cause this.

Comment: I have no vuex in my project and I have some particular components being mounted twice. Moreover other instances of the same components are fine. Didn't find a reason yet, I tried to use "key", but it didn't help