# prevent multiplied `addEventListener` in vue mounted hook injected by mixin

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, dom

### Minimal, Reproducible Example

<strike>bug or</strike> intentional?

It seems if you kinda render into a component so that two components share one `Element` leads to doubled global mixin mounts on one `$el`.

```js
Vue.mixin({
  mounted: function() {
    //debugger;
    this.$el.addEventListener("contextmenu", (w) => {
        console.log("contextmenu")
        w.stopPropagation();
        w.preventDefault();
    })
  }
});

Vue.component("App", {
  render(h) {
    return h("div", {
      style: "height: 100vh;width: 100vw;background: gray"
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h("App")
}).$mount("#el");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```

#### Mindset

Currently I build a vue-electron plugin to ease up contextmenu by the usage of decorators:

```
@MenuItems.Copy
@Component<myComponent>({})
class myComponent extends Vue{}
```

That's fine and all is working.

#### Except for some components.

Those are triggering **twice on 'contextmenu'**

The part where I inject into the hooks:

```
import Vue, { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import { remote } from 'electron';
const { Menu } = remote

export default function applyMixin(_Vue: VueConstructor){

    _Vue.mixin({
        beforeCreate: contextMenuInit,
        mounted: popup
    })

    function popup(this: Vue){
        
        const onContextmenu = ((e: Event) => {
            const menu = new Menu();
            for(let menuItem of this.$contextMenuItems){
                menu.append(menuItem)
            }
            menu.popup()
            e.preventDefault()
            e.stopPropagation()
        }).bind(this)
        // <injection of events>        
        this.$el.addEventListener('contextmenu', onContextmenu, false)
        this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy', () => {
            this.$el.removeEventListener('contextmenu', onContextmenu, false)
        })
        // </injection of events> 
    }

    function contextMenuInit(this: Vue){

        const options = this.$options 
        if(options.contextMenuItems){
            this.$contextMenuItems = options.contextMenuItems;
        } else if(options.parent && options.parent.$contextMenuItems){
            this.$contextMenuItems = options.parent.$contextMenuItems.slice()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046304/component-mounted-fires-twice-on-page-load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The FIX:

as the issue lies in parent - child both calling the registered hook and it is not wanted when they share `$el` one can simply return from the hook

### `if(this.parent && this.parent.$el === this.$el) return;`

```js
function ev(w){
    console.log("contextmenu")
    w.stopPropagation();
    w.preventDefault();
}
Vue.mixin({
  mounted: function() {
    //debugger;
    if(this.parent && this.parent.$el === this.$el) return;
    
    this.$el.addEventListener("contextmenu", ev)
    this.$once('hook:beforeDestroy', () => {
      this.$el.removeEventListener("contextmenu", ev)
    })
  }
});

Vue.component("App", {
  render(h) {
    return h("div", {
      style: "height: 100vh;width: 100vw;background: gray"
    });
  }
});

new Vue({
  render: h => h("App")
}).$mount("#el");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="el"></div>
```